# Buttons and ActionBar are ignoring the custom fonts defined in Application

Tags: java, android, fonts

Using the following code to override the font in the app, but the ActionBar and the Buttons ignore it. The rest (TextViews and EditTexts work fine). I'm using AppCompat library. Thanks for help in advance.

```
  @Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
    final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/avenir.ttc");
    replaceFont(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(R.style.AppTheme).toString(), regular);
    replaceFont("DEFAULT", regular);
}
protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
                                  final Typeface newTypeface) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Map<String, Typeface> newMap = new HashMap<String, Typeface>();
        newMap.put("sans-serif", newTypeface);

        try {
            final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                    .getDeclaredField("sSystemFontMap");
            staticField.setAccessible(true);
            staticField.set(null, newMap);



            Field sDefaults = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField("sDefaults");
            sDefaults.setAccessible(true);
            sDefaults.set(null, new Typeface[]{
                    newTypeface, newTypeface, newTypeface, newTypeface
            });

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        try {
            final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                    .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
            staticField.setAccessible(true);
            staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be great if somebody explained how does it work. (I guess the problem is that Buttons and ActionBar do not inherit some class, where the font gets overridden). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this class I found this in stack overflow itself.

```
public class TypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {
      /** An <code>LruCache</code> for previously loaded typefaces. */
    private static LruCache<String, Typeface> sTypefaceCache =
            new LruCache<String, Typeface>(12);

    private Typeface mTypeface;

    /**
     * Load the {@link Typeface} and apply to a {@link Spannable}.
     */
    public TypefaceSpan(Context context, String typefaceName) {
        mTypeface = sTypefaceCache.get(typefaceName);

        if (mTypeface == null) {
            mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getApplicationContext()
                    .getAssets(), String.format("fonts/%s", typefaceName));

            // Cache the loaded Typeface
            sTypefaceCache.put(typefaceName, mTypeface);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
        p.setTypeface(mTypeface);

        // Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
        p.setFlags(p.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.setTypeface(mTypeface);

        // Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
        tp.setFlags(tp.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
}
```

---

For using this

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My Title");
s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "MyTypeface.otf"), 0, s.length(),
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(s);
```

Am not sure whether it will work for buttons try it  :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm really looking for the kind of solution that will let me override everything at once. I hope, google has something for it. (Such a common thing and they really made it too complicated)